# Django reuse class views

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i hope this hasn't been asked, but i didn't found a suitable answer for what i was looking for.
in my Django Database Model i have a few similar Tables

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

class Elimination(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

class Inventory_location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

is there a way to define a general view for \updates\list\delete forms that reuse the same view but with different models? maybe with an URL pattern that takes a string of the model as an argument and passes it to the "generalized" view(s).

-edit: tried to clarify my answer

Comment: Seems like django admin?

Comment: no has nothing to do with Django admin, is for a simple Inventory System.